# my image slider doesn't work on all devices

Tags: java, android, image

i have created an app which contain number of buttons and each button is connected with number of photos (image slider (i think i am using image slider using viewerpage)) ....... it works perfectly on some devices such as 6.0.1 but when i am tring to use it on another devices such as 4.2.2 it stops immediately once i click on the butuon and here and i have done in xml (it's name tip_3)

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

and i have created another xml ( as the walk-through in the youtube ) (xml name algwhra )

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

and here is the java for (tips_3) :

```
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Tips_3 extends AppCompatActivity {

    ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tips_3);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

        AlGwhra viewPagerAdapter = new AlGwhra(this);

        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);



    }
}
```

and here is the (algwhra) java :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import javax.xml.transform.Result;


/**
 * Created by Hassan on 12-Jul-17.
 */

public class AlGwhra extends PagerAdapter{

    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private Integer[] images ={R.drawable.g1,R.drawable.g2,R.drawable.g3,R.drawable.g4,R.drawable.g5,R.drawable.g6,R.drawable.g7,R.drawable.g8,R.drawable.g9,R.drawable.g10,R.drawable.g11,R.drawable.g12,R.drawable.g13};

    public AlGwhra(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.algwhra, null);
        ImageView imageView =(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);

        ViewPager vp =(ViewPager) container;
        vp.addView(view ,0);
        return view;

     }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {

        ViewPager vp =(ViewPager) container;
        View view =(View) object;
        vp.removeView(view);


    }

}
```

Comment: Please add the logcat of the crash to the quesiton

Comment: can you tell me how could i make that correctly @cricket_007

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this